# How to run static html file in node.js server

Tags: node.js, static

I'm new in node.js, I have learn node.js and express framework

I know how to run server, set router and render html template basicly, but all the tutorial tell render the html by `res.send()` or `render` how can I view static file?Like static sample.html:

just like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static.html`

my file tree like:

```
root
|
|---server.js
|---static
    |---static.html
```

How can I view the static file by setting router?Or use some middleware(Better use express framework)?

**Updated:**
I have try this:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express.createServer();
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.send('Hello World');
    });
    app.configure(function () {
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
    })

    app.listen(8000);
```

but it still can not work: tell me:`Cannot GET /static/client.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the [static middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

Comment: *If* the file name is `static.html`, *then* you should request http://127.0.0.1:8000/static.html. *If* the file name is `client.html`, *then* you should request http://127.0.0.1:8000/client.html.

Answer (score 1):

Is your file named `client.html` as specified in your update or is it named `static.html` as you show in your file tree?

So, try either:

```
http://localhost:8000/client.html
```

or...

```
http://localhost:8000/static.html
```

Notice the lack of "/static" directory.

Also, put your `app.configure` line before your `app.get`.